# To fetch parent and its children connected thru one attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

Query to fetch the SEC_CODE of parent its child and all grand children. Children are connected through PREV_SEC value.

[image]

According to above image,
1. Here if sec_code is 1 then the query should return 1, 3, 4 7, 8
2. if sec_code is 2 then query return 2.
3. if sec_code is 4 then query return 4,7,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive `CTE` to get the desired output like following query.

```
WITH CTE2 (SEC_CODE,SEC_NAME,PREV_SEC)
AS (
    SELECT SEC_CODE,SEC_NAME,PREV_SEC
    FROM YOURTABLE
    WHERE SEC_CODE = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C1.SEC_CODE,C1.SEC_NAME,C1.PREV_SEC
    FROM YOURTABLE C1
    INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.PREV_SEC = C2.SEC_CODE
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
```

**Note**: Replace `YOURTABLE` with the actual table name in above query.

Comment: ORA-32039: recursive WITH clause must have column alias list

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly need an Oracle specific solution, You may try below query having CONNECT BY clause -

```
SELECT SEC_CODE,SEC_NAME,PREV_SEC
FROM YOURTABLE
START WITH SEC_CODE = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR PREV_SEC = SEC_CODE;
```